# Setting nullable int to default does not make it nul

Tags: c#

I have a nullable int. I want to set its value to `null` so I do the following:

```
int? X;
X = 1;
X = default(int?);
```

It keeps the old value of `1` instead of setting `X` to `null`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your code works fine.  Please show us a _complete_ standalone example.

Comment: And why would you not simply say `X = null` which is legal and more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't keep the value `1`, the variable gets the value `null`:

```
using System;

class Program {

  static void Main() {

    int? X;
    X = 1;
    X = default(int?);

    Console.WriteLine(X.HasValue);

  }

}
```

Output:

```
False
```